# I want to get total of items price but it doesn't show any value in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, shopping-cart

```
this.stor.get('cart').then(val => {
  var sum = 0;
  this.data = val;
  for (let i = 0; i <= this.data.length; i++) {
    this.data[i].total = this.data[i].price * this.qty;
    sum = sum + this.data[i].total;

  };

  console.log(sum)

})
```

I want to get total of every item in my cart I used this function if I console sum in the loop it will give correct value in the loop according to every ith value but not outside the loop. Where I am going wrong please tell me thank you

Comment: try `let sum: number = 0` instead of `var`;

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
let sum: number = 0;

this.data.map((val) => {
  val.total = val.price * val.qty; // this will update your total key
  sum += val.total; // this will add total to your sum
});

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
this.data = val;
const sum = this.data.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
  currentValue['total'] = currentValue.price * this.qty;
  return result + currentValue['total'];
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

That what i´m learn this function is recommended for sum values in list

```
 getTotal = () => {
        return this.{{**card list**}}.map(t => t.price).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)
      }
```